# Function that prints the name of the variables printed

Tags: python, variables, printing, names

When I use "print" statements I like to describe the name of the variables I am printing. E.g. I would do:

```
A = 1
B = 2

print(f'A = {A}\nB = {B}\n')
```

To get:

```
>> A = 1
   B = 2
```

I'd like to write a function that prints the names of the variables printed so it saves me from writing the f-string all the time.
I have tried:

```
import inspect

def new_print(*args):
    for arg in args:
        variable_name = inspect.signature(new_print)
        print(f'{variable_name} = {arg}')
    print('')   
    
  
new_print(A,B)
```

But I get:

```
(*args) = 1
(*args) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.8 you can use this [f-string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print an expression and its value instead of creating a new function:

```py
>>> a = 123
>>> print(f'{a=}')
a=123
>>> print(f'Debug output: {a*2=}')
Debug output: a*2=246
```

Comment: Actually what f-strings ending in `=` display is the "expression text", which might not be a variable name (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)). To see what I mean, change your first example to `print(f'{a*2=}')`.

Answer (score 1):

A variable's name is just a way to refer to that *value* in whatever scope you're in. It doesn't travel with the variable, and certainly not through `*args`. At most, you could send `**kwargs` and refer to the key, but you'd have to call it like `new_print(A=A, B=B)`

```
def new_print(**kwargs):
    for argname, argval in kwargs.items():
        print(f"{argname} = {argval}")
    print("")
```

Run this like so:

```
A = 1
B = 2
new_print(A=A, B=B)
```

which gives the output

```
A = 1
B = 2
```